# How do I do element-wise comparison of two arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays, comparison

I have two arrays:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,4,3]
```

Is there an element-wise comparison method in Ruby such that I could do something like this:

```
a == b
```

returns:

`[1,0,1]` or something like `[TRUE,FALSE,TRUE]`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's one way that I can think of.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 4, 3]

a.zip(b).map { |x, y| x == y } # [true, false, true]
```

Comment: Why not just do the destructuring in the block parameter instead?

Comment: @JörgWMittag - I didn't know that destructuring of array arguments was possible within the block.

Comment: It works just like it does with methods, except that you can in some cases leave off the parentheses. That's one of the differences between blocks and methods (and thus also `Proc`s and lambdas). In a method definition, if you want to do destructuring, you *have* to use parentheses, e.g. `def foo((x, y))`. Blocks are more liberal: if you declare multiple parameters but only pass a single argument, Ruby will try to perform destructuring (i.e. call `to_ary`) on the argument. Have you never used `Hash#each`? It gets passed an array consisting of the key and the value, but you usually use it …

Comment: … like this: `hsh.each {|k, v| … }`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - I use that all the time, but I didn't know enough about Ruby's internals and that it was passed as an array of two items.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use .collect

```
a.zip(b).collect {|x,y| x==y }
=> [true, false, true]
```

Comment: You can use `collect` rather than `map`? Wow!

Comment: `collect` is simply an alias for `map`. [Array#collect](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-collect)

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,4,3]
a.zip(b).map { |pair| pair[0] <=> pair[1] }
=> [0, -1, 0]
```

The **element-wise comparison** is achieved with the `zip` Ruby Array object method.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,4,3]
a.zip(b)
=> [[1, 1], [2, 4], [3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this to get exactly what you want:

```
[1,2,3].zip([1,4,3]).map { |a,b| a == b }
=> [true, false, true]
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
array1.zip(array2).map { |a, b| a == b }
```

zip creates one array of pairs consisting of each element from both arrays at that position. Imagine gluing the two arrays side by side.

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this :

```
@array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
@array2 = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
@intersection = @array1 & @array2
```

@intersection should now be ['d', 'e'].

Intersection—Returns a new array containing elements common to the two arrays, with no duplicates.

You can even try some of the ruby tricks like the following :

```
array1 = ["x", "y", "z"]  
array2 = ["w", "x", "y"]  
array1 | array2 # Combine Arrays & Remove Duplicates(Union)  
=> ["x", "y", "z", "w"]  

array1 & array2  # Get Common Elements between Two Arrays(Intersection)  
=> ["x", "y"]  


array1 - array2  # Remove Any Elements from Array 1 that are 
                 # contained in Array 2 (Difference)  
=> ["z"]
```

Comment: This doesn't return what the OP wanted.